# Connect DVD Drive to Rasberry Pi and Share

Tags: dvd

I'm wondering if we can connect an external USB DVD drive to Raspberry Pi and share it across the network which can be accessed from a Mac and Win machines. Please share you thoughts on this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPi.SE! While I think this can be done the question is quite broad as it is now and lacks to show any specifics (like what research has been done before, what has been tried so far). This is not how SE is supposed to work. Please add some more of your own thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

It can indeed be done you just need to pick a Protocol.

a. Windows normally uses SMB (`Samba` on Linux). In my experience there are many issues with establishing and maintaining connection. This is supported by Windows, Linux and OS X.

b. OS X natively uses `afp` (Apple Filing Protocol) which provides excellent support on the Mac, enabling you to mount RPi files in Finder. You need to install `netatalk` on the Pi to enable this (which also provides zeroconf discovery). There is limited support on Windows.

If you need both Windows and Mac access you can run both `Samba` and `netatalk`.

Comment: afaik OP is talking about sharing a DVD Drive, not a hard disk. So I think filesystem will (almost) always be UDF. Sharing this with Samba should be pretty straightforward as there is already a CD-drive in the sample configuration.

Comment: @LuWi oops - I misread the question. The comment on Protocol are still relevent.

Comment: What pi OS distribution would cater for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]` in the mountpoint. It will be faster than SMB/CIFS or AFP, and you don't need RW access.

Answer (score 0):

Not what OP is about, but a somewhat similar scenario: if your client is a GNU/Linux distro you can use [Network Block Device](https://nbd.sourceforge.io/) protocol to export block device of your DVD drive via network.

Here's how I made it work on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ and Fedora 31 laptop.

## Server side

(In my case, Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Raspbian 10.3)

Install & enable nbd-server:

```
apt install nbd-server
systemctl enable nbd-server
```

In main config file I had to change group to `cdrom` so that nbd-server
can access the drive device.  This is almost certainly not correct way
but it worked.

```
[generic]
    user = nbd
    group = cdrom
    includedir = /etc/nbd-server/conf.d
```

In */etc/nbd-server/conf.d/zasus.config*:

```
[zasus]
    exportname = /dev/sr0
    readonly = true
```

*zasus* is a made-up name, and will serve as export name that client
will ask for.

## Client side

(In my case, Fedora 31)

Install and enable client & kernel module:

```
sudo dnf -y install nbd-client
sudo modprobe nbd
```

This should create bunch of new files in */dev*, named *nbd0-..*.
The group is `disk`.

I decided to use *nbd11* for this setup, so in my */etc/nbdtab*:

```
nbd11 my.raspberry.hostname zasus
```

To connect the device:

```
sudo nbd-client nbd11
```

To set up access permissions, I've changed group of the device
to one that my main user was in:

```
sudo chgrp netvorovo /dev/nbd11
```

## Notes

Permission setup is kinda silly and inflexible on both sides; it worked
for me though.  If someone knows better, feel free to update this answer.

Make sure your Pi has enough power to run the DVD drive and whatever
other devices you have connected.  (Or just disconnect all other devices
if you can.)